# Se puede crear una aplicación web solo usando Python o necesariamente se necesita HTML, CSS y Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, python, css, aplicación-web

Quiero crear una apliación para android, pero también quisiera conectar esa misma base de datos a una versión para el navegador, sería aplicación web. Necesito sí o sí HTML, CSS y Javascript, o con Python puedo hacer también?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stackoverflow en espanol!, las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas (no se permiten este tipo de preguntas en la comunidad), considera pasar por el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Para android desconozco si exista alguna forma de usar python de manera eficiente como lenguaje de programacion para realizar una app para android, pero para los navegadores quiza te interese investigar sobre dJango, el cual es un framework de python, con respecto a realizar aplicaciones para android lo mas realista y de alto performance es usar Java o Kotlin, debido a que android trabaja nativamente con Java y kotlin es la mezcla de java con otro lenguaje, estos dos son los mas adecuados para apps de android.

Comment: Cuando digo "desconozco si existe alguna forma de usar python de manera eficiente para trabajar en android", me refiero a que para poder usar python como lenguaje de programacion para android, al no ser python un lenguaje nativo de android este tendra que pasar ya sea por un interprete o un compilador diferente para poder ser procesado a Java, el cual si trabaja directamente con android, con respecto a de si se puede usar solo python para crear una pagina web, django facilita un poco las cosas en ese punto... sin embargo los estilos y demas... creo que deberas conocer html y css como minimo.

Comment: Respecto a de si podrias conectarte a la misma base de datos tanto en la app movil como en la pagina web, por supuesto que si!, la mayoria de lenguajes de programacion proveen una forma de conectarse a bases de datos, entre ellos esta python, por lo que asi uses java, python, javascript, c++ o estes en una plataforma diferente, puedes conectarte a esa base de datos sin problemas, tanto en movil como en la pagina web (independiente de la plataforma y el lenguaje), eso si, deberas aprender algun lenguaje del lado del servidor tal como PHP o puedes usar el framework django mencionado.

Comment: Puedes usar el Framework Cordova con el Intérprete Brython para crear tu aplicación: https://tecnobillo.com/sections/python-en-android/Cordova-Brython/Cordova-Brython.html